# Quickly obtaining sums of sets of numbers

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, upper-bound, finite-sets

We are given a set of $n$ bits, call them $a_1$, $a_2$,...,$a_n$.  We are also given a set of $m$ sums, where the sums $s_1$, $s_2$,...,$s_k$,...,$s_m$ are given as sums of some of the bits. For example:

$$s_k = a_3 + a_5 + a_{17} + a_{22} + a_{35}$$

There is more structure to the sums, however.  The sums are split into $m / \alpha$ groups, where each sum is in only one group.  For example, and to make things easier, sums $s_1$, $s_2$,...,$s_{\alpha}$ are in group 1, sums $s_{ \alpha + 1}$,...,$s_{2\alpha}$ are in group 2, and so on.  Then we know that each bit will occur exactly once in each group.

So for example, the bit $a_1$ will appear in each group, the bit $a_2$ will appear once in each group, and so on...

**QUESTION**

How fast can we calculate all of the sums?

**MY IDEAS**

If we assume that there are $\alpha$ sums in each group, then there are at most $2^\alpha$ combinations of bits.  For example, if there are two sums, we know that there are four combinations of bits:

(0)  Bits that are not in either sum

(1)  Bits that are in sum 1 ($s_1$), but not in sum 2 ($s_2$)

(2)  Bits that are not in sum 1 ($s_1$), but are in sum 2 ($s_2$)

(3)  Bits that are in both sums.

Thus we need at most $n$ additions to calculate the sums of each of the $m / \alpha$ groups.  So our total time is at most $n(m/\alpha)$ additions, since there are $m/\alpha$ groups.

---

However, I believe that we can do better!  I'm guessing that we can also use subtraction and sums from different groups to arrive at a much better algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101400/discussion-between-asds-asds-and-matt-groff).

Comment: Is preprocessing the set of sums allowed ? (I.e. knowing which bits belong to which sums before you know the bits themselves, and the preprocessing time not being counted ?)

Comment: "I believe that we can do better!": can you give us a clue ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust:  I'm not totally sure what I was referring to, since it was a long time ago.  You mentioned common subexpressions, and I believe I was referring to adding and/or subtracting these expressions, which should give more choices as for what to calculate.  That's all I remember right now.  Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Haha, I did not notice that the post was resurfacing after years...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that we can do even better than this answer, but perhaps this will help.

We split our list of bits $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_n$ into approximately $n / \beta$ collections (these could also be called groups, but I make the distinction so that we know that these are different from the groups above).  Here we set $\beta = \log{(m/(\log{(mn)})}$ In other words, the first collection consists of the first $\beta$ bits $a_1$, $a_2$, $\dots$, $a_{\beta}$.  The second collection consists of the second $\beta$ bits $a_{\beta+1}$, $a_{\beta+2}$, $\dots$, $a_{2\beta}$, and so on.

We find all possible sums for each collection, of which there are approximately $2^{\log{(m/(\log{(mn)}))}} = m/(\log{(mn)})$.  We then calculate each of these sums exactly.  If we're careful, we can calculate each sum in constant time by adding or subtracting one bit from a sum with all other bits the same.

Thus we use roughly $m/(\log{(mn)})$ space to store each solution, times $\log{\log{(mn)}}$ maximum bits per solution, times $n / \log{(mn)}$ different collections.

The running time should be approximately $O \left( \frac{mn \log{ \log{ (mn)}}}{\log{(mn)})^2} \right)$ if I did my calculations right.

This is somewhat faster than the naive approach.  Again, I believe that we can do better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, only the bits $a_k=1$ are to be counted. Then, a given bit influences exactly one sum per group, and no sum in the same group have common terms. So a straightforward solution is to associate to every bit the list of sums it takes part to (one per group), and to accumulate that bit to these sums. This takes an effort $n+n'g$ where $n'$ denotes the number of ones and $g$ the number of groups.

Now if I am right, the only way to make it faster is by detecting common subexpressions between the groups (there are no common subexpressions within a group), and compute them once only. The extreme case would be that of all sums being identical across all groups, reducing the workload to $n+m$.

This said, finding the common subexpressions and minimizing their number seems a daunting task.